# A* pathfinding with nodes priority

Tags: c, algorithm, path-finding, maze, pacman

I'm trying to look for the shortest path in a maze with specific starting & ending points, the maze is built as a 2D table (rows and columns) when in some cells in the table you can't go through ("walls"),
so far so good and the A* algorithm works fine, the problem starts when specific cells have a **better 'weight'** then others..
for example, take 3*3 maze:

- starting point 1*1
- ending point 3*3
- the cell at 1*3 has a better weight from the others, which means if eventually you have equals routs, you better go through this cell

so by the A* it won't even get the 1*3 cell to understand that it has a better weight!

is there a solution to that issue?

thanks!

Comment: ^ that was going to be my answer

Comment: @HenkHolterman , user2144097 - Dijkstra's algorith, is basically A* with h(v) = 0. So, if you have a good heuristic function - dijkstra is inferior to A*.

Comment: @user2144097 - you can ask us but why not ask Google or wikipedia?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I disagree with your last comment. This is not a classic "how to solve a maze" question. The OP already has a maze solver, and he wants to know how to add a new aspect of 'important nodes' that should be favored by the algoithm if possible. It takes  a lot of experience on this field to think what are the correct keywords for this query, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Create the graph representing your maze `G=(V,E)`.

Create a new weighted graph with a weight function for the edges in the graph:

```
w(u,v) = 1                if v is "not important"
         1-1/(n+1)        if v is important.
(n is the total number of vertices/cells in your maze).
```

Now, note that a path that is travelling through `v` is 'better' (shorter) than a path that does not travel through it, but still shorter (in distance) paths are always favored.

You can use A* now with a modified heuristic function:

```
h'(v) = h(v)*[1-1/(n+1)]  [where h(v) is the original admissible heuristic you had]
```

**Note:** Ignore the comments, Dijsktra's Algorithm is inferior to A* if you have an admissible heuristic function, and it seems like you do.